# Dell Inspiron 15-7577 Windows 10 - Huge Title Bars and Cursors

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, laptop-display

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with a 4k screen running Windows 10.

In order to actually read any type of text, I reduce the resolution from 3840x2160 to a very normal 1920x1080 without any font scaling. For the most part, this is absolutely fine however, on occasions, the display suddenly "changes" and things go weird:

Thick black borders around floating windows
Massive cursors in some applications (others are normal)
Double-height window title bars with extra large fonts and icons
The only way to recover the situation is to reboot.

My guess is that its a graphics driver issue (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060) but I'm running the latest version.

Anyone else experienced anything similar?

Comment: Instead of resolution you should change the [scaling](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-adjust-high-dpi-scaling-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @spike_66 I've tried scaling but this introduces other issues